timer in Linux Kernel raise oops
I am working on a small project, aiming to implement a reliable transport protocol over udp. But when I tried to use timer in Linux kernel, I met some issues.
Below is the simplified code:
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <net/protocol.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <net/tcp.h>
#include <net/inet_common.h>
#include <net/udp.h>

#define IPPROTO_RUDP 141

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Zhou hongfeng");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

static struct proto rudp_prot;
static struct net_protocol rudp_protocol;

static struct inet_protosw RUDP_inetsw =
{
        .type = SOCK_DGRAM,
        .protocol = IPPROTO_RUDP,
        .prot = &rudp_prot,
        .ops = &inet_dgram_ops,
        .flags = INET_PROTOSW_REUSE,
};

struct rudp_sock{
    struct udp_sock usock;
    struct timer_list timer;
};

void retransmit_handler(struct timer_list *t)
{
    printk("timer activated!\n");
    struct rudp_sock *rsock =
        from_timer(rsock, t, timer);
    struct sock *sk = (struct sock*)rsock;
    sock_put(sk);
    sk_reset_timer(sk,&rsock->timer,jiffies+HZ);
}

int rudp_init(struct sock *sk)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Init sock!\n");
    struct rudp_sock *rsock = (struct rudp_sock*)(sk);

    timer_setup(&rsock->timer,retransmit_handler,0);

    sk_reset_timer(sk,&rsock->timer,jiffies+HZ);
    return udp_prot.init(sk);
}

void rudp_close(struct sock *sk,long timeout)
{
    struct rudp_sock *rsock = (struct rudp_sock*)sk;
    sk_stop_timer(sk,&rsock->timer);

    printk("ref: %d\n",refcount_read(&sk->sk_refcnt));

    udp_prot.close(sk,timeout);
}

int rudp_rcv(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct net_protocol *udp_protocol_ref = rcu_dereference(inet_protos[IPPROTO_UDP]);
    return udp_protocol_ref->handler(skb);
}

int rudp_err(struct sk_buff *skb, u32 info)
{
    struct net_protocol *udp_protocol_ref = rcu_dereference(inet_protos[IPPROTO_UDP]);
    return udp_protocol_ref->err_handler(skb,info);
}

void init_RUDP(void)
{
    rudp_prot = udp_prot;
    memcpy(rudp_prot.name,"RUDP\0",5);
    rudp_prot.close = rudp_close;
    rudp_prot.init = rudp_init;
    rudp_protocol.handler = rudp_rcv;
    rudp_protocol.err_handler = rudp_err;
    rudp_protocol.no_policy = 1;
    return ;
}

static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {
    init_RUDP();
    int res;
    res =  proto_register(&rudp_prot,1);

    if(res<0)
        printk(KERN_INFO "proto_register error!\n");        
    res = inet_add_protocol(&rudp_protocol,IPPROTO_RUDP);
    if(res<0)
        printk(KERN_INFO "proto add error!\n");
    inet_register_protosw(&RUDP_inetsw);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, World!\n");
    proto_unregister(&rudp_prot);   
    inet_del_protocol(&rudp_protocol,IPPROTO_RUDP);
    inet_unregister_protosw(&RUDP_inetsw);
    return ;
}


module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);


Then I run a test program, which only init a socket (not sending or receiving data). And the retransmit timer function works as expected. But when I close the test program, the Kernel raise oops sometimes, this is what command dmesg prints:
[  363.328047] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 00000001000021da
[  363.328067] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[  363.328072] #PF: error_code(0x0001) - permissions violation
[  363.328076] PGD 62a37067 P4D 62a37067 PUD 62a36067 PMD ed89067 PTE 80000000bbade865
[  363.328086] Oops: 0001 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
[  363.328095] CPU: 6 PID: 69 Comm: khungtaskd Tainted: G           OE      6.5.1 #5
[  363.328100] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 11/12/2020
[  363.328104] RIP: 0010:watchdog+0x133/0x570
[  363.328130] Code: 48 8b 50 10 48 83 c0 10 4c 8d a2 a8 f5 ff ff 48 39 c2 0f 84 36 03 00 00 44 8d 79 ff 85 c9 0f 84 8e 01 00 00 48 89 75 b8 eb 40 <41> 8b 44 24 18 25 02 05 00 00 83 f8 02 0f 84 11 01 00 00 48 8b 83
[  363.328135] RSP: 0018:ffffb73b4066be90 EFLAGS: 00010203
[  363.328139] RAX: 0000000000000019 RBX: ffff9b9bf6896ed0 RCX: 00000000003ffece
[  363.328143] RDX: 0000000100003e00 RSI: ffff9b9bf6896600 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  363.328146] RBP: ffffb73b4066bee0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  363.328149] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00000001000021c2
[  363.328152] R13: 0000000100003e00 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00000000003ffecd
[  363.328156] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9b9cf9f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  363.328159] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  363.328163] CR2: 00000001000021da CR3: 0000000001fc6000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[  363.328198] Call Trace:
[  363.328207]  <TASK>
[  363.328222]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  363.328240]  ? __die+0x24/0x80
[  363.328246]  ? page_fault_oops+0x176/0x500
[  363.328260]  ? raw_spin_rq_unlock+0x10/0x40
[  363.328276]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x31d/0x6b0
[  363.328282]  ? exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
[  363.328306]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
[  363.328322]  ? watchdog+0x133/0x570
[  363.328330]  ? __pfx_watchdog+0x10/0x10
[  363.328336]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[  363.328349]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  363.328355]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[  363.328363]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  363.328369]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  363.328384]  </TASK>
[  363.328386] Modules linked in: testModel(OE) isofs bnep vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock gameport intel_rapl_msr ac97_bus snd_pcm btusb btrtl btbcm intel_rapl_common btintel vmw_balloon btmtk snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul bluetooth binfmt_misc polyval_clmulni polyval_generic snd_seq_midi_event ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd snd_rawmidi cryptd nls_iso8859_1 snd_seq input_leds joydev serio_raw snd_seq_device snd_timer ecdh_generic snd ecc vmw_vmci soundcore sch_fq_codel mac_hid vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper drm msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse usbhid mptspi mptscsih ahci hid mptbase e1000 scsi_transport_spi libahci i2c_piix4 pata_acpi [last unloaded: testModel(OE)]
[  363.328583] CR2: 00000001000021da
[  363.328589] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  363.328592] RIP: 0010:watchdog+0x133/0x570
[  363.328637] Code: 48 8b 50 10 48 83 c0 10 4c 8d a2 a8 f5 ff ff 48 39 c2 0f 84 36 03 00 00 44 8d 79 ff 85 c9 0f 84 8e 01 00 00 48 89 75 b8 eb 40 <41> 8b 44 24 18 25 02 05 00 00 83 f8 02 0f 84 11 01 00 00 48 8b 83
[  363.328641] RSP: 0018:ffffb73b4066be90 EFLAGS: 00010203
[  363.328645] RAX: 0000000000000019 RBX: ffff9b9bf6896ed0 RCX: 00000000003ffece
[  363.328648] RDX: 0000000100003e00 RSI: ffff9b9bf6896600 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  363.328651] RBP: ffffb73b4066bee0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  363.328653] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00000001000021c2
[  363.328656] R13: 0000000100003e00 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00000000003ffecd
[  363.328659] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9b9cf9f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  363.328663] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  363.328666] CR2: 00000001000021da CR3: 0000000001fc6000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
[  363.328689] note: khungtaskd[69] exited with irqs disabled


This OOPS is not printed everytime. It appears after I close my test program for a while, sometimes it don't appears, worsely, sometimes it block my cpu directly and I have to reboot my OS.
I tried many approaches, I don't know what exactly is append in my kernel. But one thing I can make sure is, when I delete code concerning timer, it works well.
I just want to know how to use timer correctly, I think maybe there is something wrong with my usage of timer.

Nothing in the code refers to the rudp_init and rudp_close functions, so the timer has not been set up.

You probably need to change init_RUDP to assign rudp_prot.init = rudp_init; and rudp_prot.close = rudp_close;.

@IanAbbott I put the wrong code here, now I edit it. There was rudp_prot.close = rudp_close before,  but I deleted the code for testing. Now you can see the correct code.

The intermittent oops may be due to unsynchronized timer deletion in rudp_close. Replacing the call to sk_stop_timer with sk_stop_timer_sync may help, but the code also needs to prevent retransmit_handler resetting the timer by setting and checking a flag or something. You may need to lock the socket when setting or checking the flag. Also, the call to sock_put() should be at the end of the function.
